# makeRDD not assigning segments according to preferred locations

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am Using `sc.makeRDD` to distribute segment to specific worker nodes but the distribution is not on the correct node it seems like its random.
for example the data that should be on slave-2 are on slave-1 and so on.This is the code:

```
var collect = Seq((Slave1_seq,Seq("slave-1")),(Slave2_seq,Seq("slave-2")),(Slave3_seq,Seq("slave-3")),(Slave4_seq,Seq("slave-4")))
var RDD = sc.makeRDD(collect)
```

Comment: How to create a [mcve], but I would like to point out that preferred is not guaranteed.

Comment: Care to elaborate on _"the distribution is not on the correct node it seems like its random."_ How do you check it? Do you use `foreachPartition` or similar?

Comment: yes I use foreach to print out the members of the partition on each node so I can track the data.